# Vector Field notation

Tags: derivatives, notation, divergence-operator, divergence-theorem

$$\mathbf{v}(x,y,z)=\frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

I am asked to find the divergence of this vector field, however I don't recognize the form it is given in. What is the $(x,y,z)$ on the numerator?

Comment: so the first component of the field would x/sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)?

Comment: $(x,y,z)$ is in this case a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So you are right, the first component would be indeed  $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$

Comment: Ok, so to find the divergence of the field. I would have to take the partial derivative with respect to x of this first component. And then y,z for 2nd and 3rd components?

Comment: Exactly, and then you add them all together :)